# IPTV application recommendation for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, wayland

For *Ubuntu 22.04 LTS* (and potentially 24.04 LTS), what application would you recommend for *IPTV*? I really don´t know where to start, and it doesn´t seem that obvious the answer, at least from what I have been able to search.

Comment: @user535733 the only IPTV application that I know is Hypnotix, from when I started on Linux Mint, and I basically want to do that. An application in which I can select countries, shows, favourites, etc. I can paste the URL into Haruna Media Player, or Celluloid, but it doesn´t give me that functionality. Which is why I am asking, and open to suggestions.